# JPQL eagerly fetch element

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Suppose the following:

```
   @Query("SELECT new so.dto.CustomerWithTotal(s, sum(sb.amount)) from Customer s LEFT join fetch Bills sb ON sb.customer.sq=s.sq and sb.periodFrom <= ?3 and sb.periodTo >= ?2 WHERE s.department.sq=?1 group by s")
   List<CustomerWithTotal> findCustWithOrderTotal(Long departmentId, LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
```

and

```
   public CustomerWithBillTotal(CustomerEo customer, BigDecimal amount) {
      this.customer= customer;
      this.amount = (amount != null) ? amount : BigDecimal.ZERO;
   }
```

I'm trying to fetch the customers along with his order totals for a specific period. However, when I inspect the actual queries executed, I see  something like this:

```
Hibernate: select customer.id as col_0_0_, sum(bill.amount) as col_1_0_ from customers...
Hibernate: select customer.id as cpx1_19_0_, customer.jpa_version as jpa_vers2_19_0_, ...
Hibernate: select customer.id as cpx1_19_0_, customer.jpa_version as jpa_vers2_19_0_, ...
```

Hibernate is only fetching the id in the first query, and then requesting each customer individually, resulting in N+1 queries. How can I make Hibernate eagerly fetch `customer` in the first query? Preferably without listing all `customer` fields in `CustomerWithBillTotal`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the entity alias to the constructor in JPQL, Hibernate has to materialize the full object, so it will fetch all fields at some point somehow. The current implementation of the constructor expression in Hibernate will, as far as I can tell, always pass in a proxy if you pass entity aliases, so the secondary loads you are seeing are due to Hibernate loading the state. If you want to fetch only the fields that you actually need you need to list them exlicitly.

You might also like what [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has to offer.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Customer.class)
public interface CustomerWithBillTotal {
    @IdMapping("sq")
    Integer getId();
    String getCustomerName();
    // Other customer mappings you need...

    // Assuming you have a one-to-many association named "bills" in Customer
    @Mapping("COALESCE(SUM(bills.amount), 0)")
    // You can also use this if you don't have that association
    // @Mapping("COALESCE(SUM(Bills[customer.sq = VIEW(sq) AND periodFrom <= :periodFrom and periodTo >= :periodTo].amount), 0)")
    BigDecimal getAmount();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`CustomerWithBillTotal a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, CustomerWithBillTotal.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
   List<CustomerWithTotal> findByDepartmentId(Long departmentId, @OptionalParam("periodFrom") LocalDate from, @OptionalParam("periodTo") LocalDate to);
```